# How to store some JSON data coming from an API in a Room Database?

Tags: android, json, android-room

I have data coming from an API that I want to store into in the user's local storage which I want to use this data for the further process so that my application can run offline too.

And the json data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2019-10-22",
        "sites": [
            {
                "site_id": 3,
                "site_name": "Site Name3",
                "site_address": "address3",
                "site_landmark": "landmark3",
                "site_zipcode": "353446",
                "site_city": "city3",
                "site_state": "state3",
                "site_zone": "zone3",
                "site_latitude": "18.404374",
                "site_longitude": "86.553958",
                "tests": [
                    {
                        "test_id": 35,
                        "test_category_id": 2,
                        "test_name": "Express Water",
                        "collection_date": "2019-10-22 11:00:00",
                        "collection_value": 4,
                        "sample_quantity_per_test": "100 ml",
                        "sample_details_required_keys": [
                            "source_of_sample",
                            "location",
                            "description"
                        ],
                        "customer_name": "company_name3",
                        "site_id": 3,
                        "containers": [
                            "100 ml bottle * 4"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "test_id": 36,
                        "test_category_id": 1,
                        "test_name": "Water Potability",
                        "collection_date": "2019-10-22 11:00:00",
                        "collection_value": 4,
                        "sample_quantity_per_test": "1.5 Ltr",
                        "sample_details_required_keys": [
                            "source_of_sample",
                            "location",
                            "description"
                        ],
                        "customer_name": "company_name3",
                        "site_id": 3,
                        "containers": [
                            "1ltr Big Bottle * 4",
                            "500 ml Small bottle * 4"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to do store this data using Room Database but I don't know how to start I already read the Codelab for Room but I still didn't get any lead, can anyone help me through this? TIA

Comment: You can use Moshi or GSON to convert it into a Entity/Model class and then store it usimg room

Comment: first you need to use GSON and store this data using models classes, then you need to use Room to store this data in data base. You will have to learn everything yourself. What I suggest learn how to use GSON first to store data and try and learn Room.

Comment: I did create model classes and I do have data coming in them. I just wanted to sav my time from learning how Room will work cause I'm close to my project's deadline @Faisal

Comment: Ok for that I'll tell you that, you need to carry out allCRUD operations using background tasks. I used Room in my project but its not complex like one you have to create. If you want I can put my code up but even then you need to explore a lot.